# How to install TigerVNC on MacOS?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have downloaded [DMG file from their site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tigervnc/files/latest/download) and opened it, which gave me

[image]

What to do next? Clicking `TigerVNC Viewer 1.11.0` icon has no effect.

Comment: What does the ReadMe say?

Comment: ReadMe says "There is no application set to open the document" :D

Comment: Try using a text reader or preview.

Comment: @SolarMike it's different topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single clicking on the `TigerVNC Viewer 1.11.0` package would have no effect except for selecting it.

You can install the app by dragging and dropping the package into the `/Applications` folder.

Comment: I did double clicking. Dragging worked, thanks.